# What happens when Git LFS is not installed?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a repository using Git LFS, and I need to understand how to instruct my co-developers to work with it. In particular I am puzzled about what happens when working with a machine where Git LFS is not installed: I would have said that cloning from such a machine would result in missing files (i.e. those stored in the LFS), but from a quick try I see those files in the code tree.
So I'd need some clarifications about this and about what kind of misbehavior I can expect for systems where Git LFS is not installed.

Comment: Did you verify that the files you saw have the expected content, or did you mistake the LFS file stubs for the actual files?

Comment: Yes, they are actually stubs/pointers as pointed out below by bk2204. My bad, I didn't check the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with Git LFS, any file with the attribute `filter=lfs` is designed to be stored with Git LFS.  When a file is stored with Git LFS, the contents committed in the object are a pointer file.  Files that are not stored with Git LFS are simply normal Git objects.

If Git LFS is not installed and the repository uses Git LFS, then when a clone or checkout of an LFS file happens, the pointer file is written into the tree instead of Git LFS being invoked to write the large object.  As a result, typically that file doesn't work with whatever software was supposed to process it, but this can be an acceptable choice in many contexts.

More seriously, if a contributor not using Git LFS checks in a file that was supposed to be managed by Git LFS, then they will check it in as a regular Git object.  [The Git LFS FAQ outlines what happens](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-faq.adoc), but typically, users who *do* have Git LFS installed will often see the file as perpetually modified, and even `git reset --hard` cannot fix that.  The FAQ recommends a CI-based approach to prevent those commits from being merged:

> The command `git lfs fsck --pointers BASE..HEAD` (with suitable values of `BASE` and `HEAD`) may be used in your CI system to verify that nobody is introducing such problems.

Note that this requires Git LFS 3.0.2 or later to work properly.